# How do I make the text of a bullet point start the new line after the bullet?

Tags: margins, itemize

This is what a normal 'itemize' does:

- some text that is too long for one line, so it

continues here

And this is what I'd like:

- some text that is too long for one line, so it

  continues here.

Basically I would like to have no text right under the bullet

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which documentclass do you use? Can you please add a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Based on guessing about your document class and page layout. What you like to have is standard behavior of `itemize` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   some text that is too long for one line, so it
\item   some text that is too long for one line, so it continues here.
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that simply indenting \begin{itemize} does the job

Comment: @JackieDaSilva, yes, it is quite simple. For start of using the LaTeX you only need to know some basic commands and environments. In this may be of help to read/consult https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf

Comment: @JackieDaSilva: No, you don't have to indent the environment for that to work, it's normal behavior. It may not look that way in your editor but when you typeset the document it will behave the way you want,